# Can we have some text passed as variables in a text file to validate the result in Ruby Cucumber framework

Tags: ruby, cucumber, nokogiri, pdf-reader

I have a XML file(Input file) which I use to generate a PDF file(Output file) which is basically a letter sent to the customers. I have to automate the validation of PDF content. I am able to get the text in PDF using PDF-Reader gem. Now I have to validate this text.

This PDF contains some static text(Text that will remain same for every customer) like, the Heading of the letter, sender address, part of the text in body of the letter, but things like Recipient address and name, Account number payment amount in the body of the letter will change for every customer.

These changing values I can get from XML. So to automate the validation I want to  use a text file that has the static text and for the dynamic text I want to pass a the value from the XML using Nokogiri gem.

Then compare this text file with the PDF text. 
I need some help in creating this text file with the variables.

Or if any one has any other suggestion please suggest ?

Example:
Sample XML:

```
<RealTimeLetter>
<Customer>
<RTLtr_LetterNumber>00510</RTLtr_LetterNumber>      
<RTLtr_CustomerAddress1>Recipient address1</RTLtr_CustomerAddress1>
<RTLtr_CustomerAddress2>*</RTLtr_CustomerAddress2>
<RTLtr_CustomerCity>CITY</RTLtr_CustomerCity>
<RTLtr_CustomerState>STATE</RTLtr_CustomerState>
<RTLtr_CustomerZip>221501020</RTLtr_CustomerZip>
<RTLtr_CustomerName>Recipient name1</RTLtr_CustomerName>
<RTLtr_CustomerSSN>111111111</RTLtr_CustomerSSN>
<RTLtr_ActNum>1111111</RTLtr_ActNum>
</Customer> 
<Customer>
<RTLtr_LetterNumber>00510</RTLtr_LetterNumber>      
<RTLtr_CustomerAddress1>Recipient address2</RTLtr_CustomerAddress1>
<RTLtr_CustomerAddress2>*</RTLtr_CustomerAddress2>
<RTLtr_CustomerCity>CITY</RTLtr_CustomerCity>
<RTLtr_CustomerState>STATE</RTLtr_CustomerState>
<RTLtr_CustomerZip>221501020</RTLtr_CustomerZip>
<RTLtr_CustomerName>Recipient name2</RTLtr_CustomerName>
<RTLtr_CustomerSSN>111111111</RTLtr_CustomerSSN>
<RTLtr_ActNum>2222222</RTLtr_ActNum>
</Customer>  
</RealTimeLetter>
```

Sample PDF Text:

```
Sender Name                                                            Letter Send Date
Sender Address                                                         Letter Heading
Sender City, State zip

Recipient name                                                        Account #: 1111111    
Recipient address
Recipient City, state zip


Dear Recipient name,
Body of the letter. Some text in this will not change. Payment amount $1234. The amount will keep chenge.

Paragraph 2. XXXXXXXXXXXX.yyyyyyyy.

Sincerely,

Customer Care Department
Sender Signature
```

I want to be able to put the value of the tag

```
<RTLtr_CustomerAddress1>Recipient address1</RTLtr_CustomerAddress1>
```

as a variable in the text file that also has the other static text in it. and be able to compare it with the text extracted from PDF.

Comment: Are you trying to test that your code works, or are you trying to test every PDF that you create?

Comment: I am trying to test every PDF that I create. I can validate the text that is static in one test case. And the dynamic text I can validate in another test case. But If I have to validate both together how do I do that ? I am looking for this.